# UITableviewcell cell.textlabel.text repeats when scrolling the tableview? how to avoid the cell.textlabel.text repetation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 1";
              break;

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 2";
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 3";
            break;

        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 4";
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 5";
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text=@" ";

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "cell.textlabel.text repeats when scrolling the tableview" ? You mean to say, that the texts of all the cell are same in particular section?

Comment: Please look at my answer posted below, which is not ignoring dequeuing of cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reuse cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` for better performance and memory optimisation.

Your core issue is something else. You are not reseting cell before re-using it. My advise to you would be reset the cell text label after dequeue operation something like this `cell.textLabel.text = @""` and then set your labels in your switch.

**I recommend trying this once before you switch to not re-using cells.**

Essentially, this is how your code should look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];
    cell.textLabel.text = @""; // Reset Text Label before re-using

     ... rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Solved by dequeueing cells, right? And not via accepted answer here because that causes memory issues...

Comment: here i need to some array datas to set value in cell rite?

Comment: Not at all... By "... rest of your code..." I meant to use your Switch the way you are doing in your example. I just want to reset the text label after dequeueing it. Try this once.

Answer (score 1):

use cell Identifier different

For example like bellow...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        /// write your code here..
    }
}
```

OR set nil like bellow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";    

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
        /// write your code here..
    }
}
```

Comment: setting dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil is not a good way i think. any way thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Do not reuse the cell is the simplest to achieve this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 1";
                break;

            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 2";
                break;

            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 3";
                break;

            case 3:
                cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 4";
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.textLabel.text=@"Sub-Scheme 5";
                break;


            default:
                break;

        }

    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text=@" ";

    }

    return cell;
}
```

hope it work for you .

Comment: If you are not re-using the cell, then it will lead to huge memory leak.

Comment: why we are not checking the cell == nil in this?

Comment: because  allready alloc the cell in second line . cell never gets null after allocating cell.

Answer (score 1):

See the below coding.I tried this.When I scroll the tableview the cell.textLabel.text is not repeated

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayRepeat;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
   arrayRepeat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sub-Scheme 1",@"Sub-Scheme 2",@"Sub-Scheme 3",@"Sub-Scheme 4",@"Sub-Scheme 5", nil];
```

UITableViewDataSource Methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return arrayRepeat.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
   if (cell == nil) 
   {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayRepeat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  

   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well cells must be reused and not dequeuing them is never a good solution. The problem you are facing is of course related to the dequeuing of the cell but it can be resolved if provide values to the text label for all cases.

If you replace your default case with this one may resolve your issue:

`default: cell.textLabel.text=@"";
          break;`